# Can a shape be both similar and congruent?

Tags: geometry

I know that congruent shapes have the same size and the rotations don't matter.  I just want to know if congruent shapes can also be similar at the same time.  I've seen that similar shapes have one shape that is a different size in comparison to another shape with proportional sides and the same angles.  So is it safe to say that congruent shapes can also be similar?

Comment: What proportion would make them congruent?

Comment: The proportions for congruent shapes are always the same.

Comment: If you mean the proportion is equal to $1$, you are correct.  Congruent shapes are a special case of similar triangles.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: not only for triangles :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it is safe to say so.  In general, if two shapes are congruent, then they must also be similar.

Answer (score 1):

All congruent shapes are similar (the ratio is 1:1 for corresponding sides), but not all similar shapes are congruent (since the corresponding sides of similar shapes are proportional, the ratios are the same but may not (and probably won't) simplify to 1:1).

Answer (score 0):

Congruency, by definition, implies that the shapes are **identical**, in terms of side lengths, dimensions and angles. For two triangles ABC and A'B'C', we get A=A',B=B',C=C'.

Similarity implies that the relationship between side lengths is identical for each corresponding pair of sides i.e. the ratio is the same between side length A and A', and B and B' and C and C'. Here, A/A' = B/B'=C/C'.

If A = A', B=B' etc., then clearly the ratio is shared for each corresponding side, i.e. the ratio is always 1. Hence, congruent implies similar, and is a stronger geometric property.

Side lengths 1,2,3 and 2,4,6 produce a similar pair of triangles, but not a congruent pair. Hence, similar does **not** imply congruent.